No puedo crear mi exe con React
he creado una app con reactjs y electron, mi objetivo es tener una app para Windows. El problema radica en que al ejecutar mi app en desarrollo funciona perfectamente, es decir con npm start y electron ., me carga bien mi app en el navegador y también en la ventana de electron. Pero ahora que hice el build, mi app ni siquiera carga con serve -s build, quiero destacar que estoy usando react router dom. Podría ayudarme por favor
